# Wordpress Fields getting swapped when having specific values

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a strange one, but it seems like it should be really easy to solve.

I have a wordpress website `Version 4.8.3`. PHP 5.6.32.

Whenever I put in a specific value into the title field `6147989800` (or other fields) it get's swapped out on the front end with `8552226270`.

I searched in every file on the server for some code (i suspect javascript) that is swapping out the numbers. No luck.

When I search the database the original number `6147989800` is there. But when I do a var_dump of the field is shows `8552226270` and it shows up as `8552226270` on the front end.

This switch happens when I put in `6147989800`, `614.798.9800`, and `614-798-9800`.

I'm at a loss. Even stranger is that when I duplicate the website to a local instance and on a test server the swap doesn't happen.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a service like CallRail.com, which automatically replaces normal phone numbers with specific ones for tracking leads?

Comment: As an aside, both of your numbers are US telephone numbers. The 855 area code code is toll-free. Both appear to be for US law firms.

Comment: Gravitate Event Tracking is being used but I don't see anywhere where a number is swapped. Also, I searched the database for those numbers using the LIKE '% 8552226270%'. but no luck

Comment: Does the 855 number show up when you look at the page's source? I.e. in your browser's "View Source" option from the raw page data, not just examining it in your browser's inspector (which would allow JS to execute beforehand). Also, when you put in your original number with formatting (e.g. dashes in `614-798-9800`), does the 855 number keep that formatting?

Comment: The 855 does not show up in the source. And yes it keeps the same formatting that is entered.

Comment: Sounds like there's some JS on the page that's causing this, then. I'd deactivate plugins one-by-one to see if you can identify the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John Ellmore for your help. It did end up being a third party Javascript that was doing the phone swap.

I don't know how I missed it [smacks palm against forehead]